# Equivalence between limits in finite dimensional vector spaces over R and R^m

Tags: limits, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider two normed vector finite dimensional spaces $V,W$ and a function $f:V\rightarrow W$.  These have their bases $\mathcal{B}_V=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}\subseteq V, \mathcal{B}_W=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}\subseteq W$. Consider projection to coordinates $\pi_V:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\pi_W:W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We can then define $\tilde{f}=\pi_W \circ f \circ \pi_V^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. I wish to prove the following:

> Theorem: Let $f:V\rightarrow W$ be a function. Then
> $$
> \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = c \text{ if and only if } \lim_{x\to \tilde{a}}\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{c}
> $$
> where $\tilde{c}=\pi_W(c)$ and $\tilde{a}=\pi_V(a)$.

I started with $\Rightarrow$ and assumed arbitrary neighbourhood of $\tilde{c}$ and tried to apply the preimage $\pi_W^{-1}$ to get a neighbourhood of $c$ in $W$ and apply the assumption on the left limit. But I am quite stuck on how to reason that preimage under $\pi_W$ of a neighbourhood is also a neighbourhood. Surely the projections are bijections. But what about preserving norms etc.? How to approach this problem and not get lost in so many $\varepsilon-\delta$ formalism?

Comment: Hint: $\pi_V$ is a vector space isomorphism. So you effectively have two norms on $\Bbb{R}^m$, the Euclidean norm  say and the one induced by the norm on $V$, let's call these $\|\cdot\|_e$ and $\|\cdot\|_V$. Show that there are positive constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha\|x\|_e \le \|x\|_V \le \beta\|x\|_e$ for all $x$. This implies that $\pi_V$ is a homeomorphism between $V$ viewed as a topological space and $\Bbb{R}^m$ with the usual topology. Similarly for $\pi_W$.

Comment: It kinda makes sense that the projections are vector space isomorphisms (that's from linear algebra). But I don't see why these should be homeomorphisms of the underlying topological spaces or even preserve the norms etc. although *it makes sense that they should* Also, how do i continue in the proof with the fact that $\pi$'s are homeomorphisms?

Comment: linear algebra tells you the $\pi$'s are linear bijective with linear inverse (i.e vector space isomorphisms). Now, $\pi_V:V \to \Bbb{R}^m$ certainly doesn't have to preserve the norms, but what is true is that given a norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert_V$ on $V$, we can use the isomorphism $\pi_V$ to get a norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert_{\pi_V}$ on $\Bbb{R}^m$. But, we also have the Euclidean norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert_e$ on $\Bbb{R}^m$. By using the equivalence of norms mentioned in the previous comments, it shows $\pi_V$ is continuous with continuous inverse, hence a homeomorphism.

Comment: $V$ is isomorphic as a normed space with $\Bbb{R}^m$ under the norm $\|\cdot\|_V$. The existence of the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as above show that every open $\|\cdot\|_e$-ball is also an $\|\cdot\|_V$-ball and vice versa. Once you know the $\pi$'s are homeomorphisms, you can just use them to translate witnesses to the convergence of $f$ to witness of the convergence of $\tilde f$.

Comment: Once you prove $\pi$'s are homeomorphisms, note that $\tilde{f} = \pi_W \circ f \circ \pi_V^{-1}$, so if you assume $f$ is continuous, then $\tilde{f}$ being a composition of continuous maps is continuous. Conversely, if you assume $\tilde{f}$ is continuous then $f = \pi_W^{-1}\circ \tilde{f}\circ \pi_V$ is also a composition of continuous maps hence continuous.

Comment: I still don't see how to use the equivallence of norms to show that $\pi$'s are homeomorphisms.